# Frontend need for Handlebars.compile. but handlebars already in use with bigcommerce serverside

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, handlebars.js, bigcommerce

I am developing a bigcommerce stencil theme. I want to use basic handlebars functionality like

`markup`

```
    <div id="mobile"></div>
    <script id="mobile_category_template" type="text/x-handlebars-template">
      <div class="entry">
        <h1>{{var}}</h1>
        <div class="body">
          <p>body</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </script>
    <script src="{{cdn 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.0.10/handlebars.min.js'}}"></script>
    <script src="{{cdn '/assets/js/category.js'}}"></script>
```

`javascript`

```
    var hitTemplate = Handlebars.compile($("#mobile_category_template").html());
    $(".collection-page").html(hitTemplate({
      var: "var works"
    }));
```

This would normally work. but bigcommerce parses handlebars `serverside`. By the time my frontend handlebars parse, the `{{var}}` has already been compiled. How can i get the above to work separately from serverside handlebars? OR how do i make and/or extend the current handlebars logic. (basically how can define my own template variables/drops)

Very specifically. I want to decide rather to load `{{> components/mobile}}` or `{{> components/desktop}}` based on the viewport or browser in use (easily done with javascript).

This is the problem i want to solve: [BigCommerce Stencil — load component parts based on custom javascript logic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634986/bigcommerce-stencil-load-component-parts-based-on-custom-javascript-logic)

Comment: You can't extend the current logic that compiles server side. You can have a client side implementation of handlebars which would support this, but it would help if you clarified what kind of functionality you are looking to achieve.

Comment: Hi @Alyss ! This link asks a more specific question. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634986/bigcommerce-stencil-load-component-parts-based-on-custom-javascript-logic

Comment: @Alyss "`You can have a client side implementation of handlebars`" This sounds interesting.

Comment: There's a good example and discussion here about it: https://github.com/wycats/handlebars.js/issues/221

Comment: @Alyss I dont think i can `{{{{raw-helper}}}}` on my end.