# BigCommerce Stencil — load component parts based on custom javascript logic

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, bigcommerce

I am using BigCommerce Stencil to make a theme. Currently `{{> components/category/category}}` will load the markup from `components/category/category.html` but now i want to do something like the following

```
  {{#if !isMobile}}
    {{> components/category/category}}
  {{else}}
    {{> components/category/category_mobile}}
  {{/if}}
```

to do that; I would need to make my own `isMobile()` function and return a `{{isMobile}}` out of it.

First attempt: `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44634630/frontend-need-for-handlebars-compile-but-handlebars-already-in-use-with-bigcomm?noredirect=1#comment76255240_44634630`

Im open to any solutions. Im just fishing for new methodes of making these themes

Questions:

1. Sense handlebars is working serverside; is this possibe?
2. Can I reload handlebars on the frontend? (see the 1st attempt link above)
3. if i can reload handle bars in the frontend in what ways can it theoretically work with the original serverside parsing to achieve the example logic above?

Comment: Based on this, you can utilize modernizr (which is available in Cornerstone) https://modernizr.com/ or you can put a PR against Paper https://github.com/bigcommerce/paper to get this functionality.

Comment: Would it not make more sense to get your "isMobile" function to the server? (Disclaimer: I have no clue about BigCommerce Stencil, but [this docs page](https://stencil.bigcommerce.com/docs/customizing-javascript) reads like that was possible)

Comment: @Tomalak I dont think bigcommerce will allow me to extend the serverside logic. But your link brings up a good point. let me look into it.

Comment: @Alyss I cant understand what exactly https://github.com/bigcommerce/paper does. Do you know of any other pages to read up or see examples or more docs?

Comment: It is used to render the themes using Handlebars template engine serverside.

Comment: I think you'll probably be better off just handling this type of logic on the client-side using match-media or media queries.  Since you're looking to execute logic based on properties of the client, the client-side is probably the path of least resistance to do so.  I'd just structure the handlebars template to be the "mobile" version, and then pass any additional data required for an enhanced "desktop" version to your client-side code via Stencil's inject helper.  I've used that basic methodology on a couple themes with pretty solid results.  Good luck!

Comment: that is kind of what I needed to know... I wonder if I can get bigCommerce to build some kind of media-query handlebar logic so that we can do that kind of thing... still open to other ideas still

Comment: It would sound good to do a front-end implementation of Handlebars, but in my experience this isn't useful as you can't  use the server side data sent by BC without making it publicly available to the client side, in which case you will be better just making your own front-end with Drupal or whatever and connecting to BC trough an API. The workaround that works for our team is to use css and js as needed, which is not too bad considering BC's front-end is pretty sketchy to begin with